# Infinite loop getting stored procedure name from DDL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, regex, oracle

I have this regular expression to check if a DLL have a prodcedure

```
var expReg = "(((ALTER|CREATE|OR|REPLACE| )*)+)?PROCEDURE.*";    
return (Regex.IsMatch(textProcedure, expReg, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

I use it with SQL Server or Oracle DLL.

Sometimes works, and sometime have a infinite loop.

What is the problem? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to match? Please, give some sample strings and expected result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why my Python regular expression pattern run so slowly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27448200/why-my-python-regular-expression-pattern-run-so-slowly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pattern of the form `(X*)+` is a very bad idea in regex, because it can cause [*catastrophic backtracking*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). This kind of pattern forces the regex engine to try all the possible combinations before failing. This can take a long time.

In your case, I think the `*` is not required, simply use:

```
(?:ALTER|CREATE|OR|REPLACE|\s)+PROCEDURE
```

I've removed the `?` too because otherwise the mere presence of the word `PROCEDURE` would be sufficient for the pattern to match.

This can be further simplified to:

```
(?:ALTER|CREATE|REPLACE)\s+PROCEDURE
```

Since it should be sufficient to match `REPLACE PROCEDURE` in the string `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE`.

Comment: Thanks Lucas. You send a solution, and a cause of my poor regular expresion. I think that your solution can help some people.