# Why my Python regular expression pattern run so slowly?

Tags: python, regex

Please see my regular expression pattern code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import re

print 'Start'
str1 = 'abcdefgasdsdfswossdfasdaef'
m = re.match(r"([A-Za-z\-\s\:\.]+)+(\d+)\w+", str1) # Want to match something like 'Moto 360x'
print m # None is expected.
print 'Done'
```

It takes 49 seconds to finish, any problem with the pattern?

Comment: `([A-Za-z\-\s\:\.]+)+` --> `[A-Za-z\-\s\:\.]+`

Comment: because there's a zillion different ways your regex can match the string, and the engine is backtracking and trying each of the variations.

Comment: More information on what and why a regex is backtracking and how catastrophic it becomes when you don't match: http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [Runaway Regular Expressions: Catastrophic Backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

In brief, if there are extremely many combinations a substring can be split into the parts of the regex, the regex matcher may end up trying them all.

Constructs like `(x+)+` and `x+x+` practically guarantee this behaviour.

To detect and fix the problematic constructs, the following concept can be used:

- At conceptual level, the presence of a problematic construct means that your regex is *ambiguous* - i.e. *if you disregard greedy/lazy behaviour, there's no single "correct" split of some text into the parts of the regex* (or, equivalently, a subexpression thereof). So, to avoid/fix the problems, you need to see and eliminate all ambiguities.

  - One way to do this is to

    - always split the text into its *meaningful parts* (=parts that have separate meanings for the task at hand), and
    - define the parts in such a way that they cannot be confused (=using the same characteristics that you yourself would use to tell which is which if you were parsing it by hand)

Comment: Is something of the form `(x+y)+` equally dangerous, or is that less likely to be a problem?

Comment: @jpmc26 It isn't unless something matches both `x` and `y` or `y` can be a blank match between `x`'s.

Comment: It's also worth noting that this is not an inherent problem with regular expressions, but an issue due to a design decision in many common regex libraries. The RE2 engine does not have this issue.

Comment: @thatotherguy What you gave as example is [the other approach to matching: text-directed](http://www.regular-expressions.info/engine.html). It does avoid the problem but it cannot use some features like lazy quantifiers or backreferences.

Answer (score 0):

Just repost the answer and solution in comments from nhahtdh and Marc B:

`([A-Za-z\-\s\:\.]+)+` --> `[A-Za-z\-\s\:\.]+`

Thanks so much to nhahtdh and Marc B!